# Are there currently any clubs that have more European titles than domestic titles (excluding minor domestic titles)?

Tags: football, awards

In the years between its victories in the 1993 European Supercup and the 2001-02 Coppa Italia, the club formerly known as [Parma A.C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parma_A.C.) had the rare distinction of having more European titles than domestic ones (not counting minor domestic titles, like championships of lower divisions or regional tournaments). The tally now stands at 4:4.

Are there currently any clubs that have more European titles than domestic ones (again, excluding minor domestic titles)? I had put my hopes with Nottingham Forest, but it turns out that their tally stands at 3 European titles (2 European Cups, 1 European Supercup) and at least 4 domestic (1 League, 2 FA Cups, 1 Charity Shield), perhaps 8 if you want to count League Cups.

Comment: As an aside, the League Cup is much more a proper trophy than the Charity Shield, which is pretty much a pre-season friendly.

Comment: Not counting Copa del Rey: Sevilla has 4 times won the Europa League and just once won the League. But with 5 cup wins, it's no longer valid. But still worth to mention imho :D

Comment: It is highly unlikely that any such thing would happen, because of the high number of domestic competitions, and the need to qualify to compete in European competitions. Even if it does happen, it will be within a short period of time, not over their entire history as a club.

Comment: @Don_Biglia now Sevilla is 7:6. Domestic: 1 league, 5 cup wins, 1 supercopa. European: 5 Europa League, 1 Super cup.

Answer (score 4):

After doing a research which includes Champions league, UEFA cup & super cup  winners I found that there are **no** teams that fits the criteria of more european titles than domestic titles.

But I found that Bayer 04 Leverkusen has a 1:1 tally winning 1 German cup (1992–93) and 1 UEFA Cup (1987–88).

Ipswich Town is also a team to mention holding a 2:1 tally winning 2 domestic titles (Champion - 1961–62, cup - 1977–78) and 1 UEFA Cup (1980-81).

also as mentioned in the comments Sevilla FC has a 7:6 tally.

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_04_Leverkusen#Honours
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipswich_Town_F.C.#Honours
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sevilla_FC#Honours